# Columns located within a column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract a dataframe from a web api and can't seem to work out how to break columns out. For Home and Away, they have breakdowns inside them, so should read Home Wins, Home Draws etc.

```
url = "http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/398/leagueTable/?matchday=38"
response = requests.get(url)
response_json = response.content
result = json.loads(response_json)
football = pd.DataFrame(result['standing'], columns=['position','teamName','playedGames','wins','draws','losses','goals', 
                                                 'goalsAgainst','home','away','goalDifference','points'])
football

football.home
```

this shows the problem:

```
0     {u'wins': 12, u'losses': 1, u'draws': 6, u'goa...
```

Comment: Could you provide a clearer example of desired output vs current output? It's a little hard to tell what you want at the moment.

Comment: sure, sorry ... my dataframe shows all columns as suggested above, with for example the first record showing: Position "1", teamName "Leceister", playedGames "38" etc etc, until it gets to home, where it shows: {u'wins': 12, u'losses': 1, u'draws': 6, u'goals etc (obviously the actual column breakdown should be: 'Home wins'; 'Home losses'; 'Home draws' etc, but only shows as a single column

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize  

url = "http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/398/leagueTable/?matchday=38"

result = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)
#print (result)

df = json_normalize(result["standing"])
```

```
print (df)
                              _links.team.href  away.draws  away.goals  \
0    http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/338           6          33   
1     http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/57           7          34   
2     http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/73           7          34   
3     http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/65           7          24   
4     http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/66           4          22   
5    http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/340           6          20   
6    http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/563           7          31   
7     http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/64           4          30   
8     http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/70           5          19   
9     http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/61           5          27   
10    http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/62           9          24   
11    http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/72           5          22   
12   http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/346           3          20   
13    http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/74           8          14   
14   http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/354           6          20   
15  http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/1044           4          22   
16    http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/71           6          25   
17    http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/67           3          12   
18    http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/68           2          13   
19    http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/58           3          13   

    away.goalsAgainst  away.losses  away.wins  \
0                  18            2         11   
1                  25            4          8   
2                  20            3          9   
3                  20            5          7   
4                  26            8          7   
5                  19            6          7   
6                  25            5          7   
7                  28            7          8   
8                  31            8          6   
9                  23            7          7   
10                 25            5          5   
11                 32           10          4   
12                 31           10          6   
13                 22            7          4   
14                 28            8          5   
15                 33            9          6   
16                 42           10          3   
17                 41           14          2   
18                 37           14          3   
19                 41           15          1   

                                             crestURI  draws  goalDifference  \
0   http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/63/...     12              32   
1   http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/53/...     11              29   
2   http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/b4/...     13              34   
3   http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/f/fd/...      9              30   
4   http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/d/da/...      9              14   
5   http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/c/c9/...      9              18   
6   http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/e/e0/...     14              14   
7   http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/0/0a/...     12              13   
8   http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/a/a3/...      9             -14   
9   http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/5/5c/...     14               6   
10  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/f/f9/...     14               4   
11  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/a/ab/...     11             -10   
12  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2...      9             -10   
13  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/8/8b/...     13             -14   
14  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bf/...      9             -12   
15  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/4/41...      9             -22   
16  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/6/60/...     12             -14   
17  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/5/56/...     10             -21   
18  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/8/8c/...      7             -28   
19  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/9/9f/...      8             -49   

    goals  ...   home.goals  home.goalsAgainst  home.losses  home.wins  \
0      68  ...           35                 18            1         12   
1      65  ...           31                 11            3         12   
2      69  ...           35                 15            3         10   
3      71  ...           47                 21            5         12   
4      49  ...           27                  9            2         12   
5      59  ...           39                 22            5         11   
6      65  ...           34                 26            3          9   
7      63  ...           33                 22            3          8   
8      41  ...           22                 24            7          8   
9      59  ...           32                 30            5          5   
10     59  ...           35                 30            8          6   
11     42  ...           20                 20            5          8   
12     40  ...           20                 19            7          6   
13     34  ...           20                 26            8          6   
14     39  ...           19                 23           10          6   
15     45  ...           23                 34            9          5   
16     48  ...           23                 20            7          6   
17     44  ...           32                 24            5          7   
18     39  ...           26                 30            8          6   
19     27  ...           14                 35           12          2   

    losses  playedGames  points  position                 teamName  wins  
0        3           38      81         1        Leicester City FC    23  
1        7           38      71         2               Arsenal FC    20  
2        6           38      70         3     Tottenham Hotspur FC    19  
3       10           38      66         4       Manchester City FC    19  
4       10           38      66         5     Manchester United FC    19  
5       11           38      63         6           Southampton FC    18  
6        8           38      62         7       West Ham United FC    16  
7       10           38      60         8             Liverpool FC    16  
8       15           38      51         9            Stoke City FC    14  
9       12           38      50        10               Chelsea FC    12  
10      13           38      47        11               Everton FC    11  
11      15           38      47        12          Swansea City FC    12  
12      17           38      45        13               Watford FC    12  
13      15           38      43        14  West Bromwich Albion FC    10  
14      18           38      42        15        Crystal Palace FC    11  
15      18           38      42        16          AFC Bournemouth    11  
16      17           38      39        17           Sunderland AFC     9  
17      19           38      37        18      Newcastle United FC     9  
18      22           38      34        19          Norwich City FC     9  
19      27           38      17        20           Aston Villa FC     3  

[20 rows x 22 columns]
```